# Can High Wind Speed bent Steel Pipes?

Tags: material-science, glass

Planning on using Steel Pipes as frames for holding laminated glass in a high wind area. Four sides will be covered by glass and the roofing will be also be covered with glass. Planning on using a frame to hold the vertical glass and for roofing support for the glass as well. Can high wind(around 150 miles per hour) bend the steel pipes and break the laminated glass?
Are there any other materials I need to consider in such a high wind speed region?

Comment: You might consider [diy.se] and [engineering.se]

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say much here unless you tell us the size of the structure, which will determine the wind pressure. However, 150 mph wind speed is a category 4 hurricane, so I would think you need to consider the effect of flying debris as well. If this project is anything larger than a very small greenhouse, you need professional advice from a structural engineer, not from random strangers on the internet.

Comment: It's around the size of a small greenhouse. The area is approximately 9ft in width,16ft in length and 8ft in height. Flying debris is also one of the reason's I'm planning on using Laminated Glass.

Comment: @TurbulentSecret That's a lot of glass - over 50 square metres by my reckoning. IMO this is not something you should be designing yourself unless you are *very* experienced.